# Entity Framework 6.1 - The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object context

Tags: entity-framework-6

I am getting below error while calling DbContext.SaveChanges().

**The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message: AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict with another object in the ObjectStateManager. Make sure that the key values are unique before calling AcceptChanges.**

The below code gives me error on call of DbContext.SaveChanges() i.e. for loop.

```
if (ID == null || ID == 0)
        {

            Models.Employee obj = new Models.Employee();
            obj.NAME = Name;
            obj.ID = GetNextSequenceValue();
            var savedObj = DbContext.Employees.Add(obj);
            DbContext.SaveChanges(); // this SaveChanges executes successfully.
            savedId = savedObj.ID;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Parameters.Length; i++)
        {
            Models.EmployeeDetail obj = new Models.EmployeeDetail;
            obj.ID = Convert.ToInt32(savedId);
            obj.KEY = Parameters[i].Key;
            obj.VALUE = Parameters[i].Value;
            DbContext.EmployeeDetails.Add(obj);
        }
**// error code**
 DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

However when I change my code to below (please see the for loop code), it works fine. But as performance consideration, I'm hitting DB on every call of for-loop.

```
if (ID == null || ID == 0)
                {

                    Models.Employee obj = new Models.Employee();
                    obj.NAME = Name;
                    obj.ID = GetNextSequenceValue();
                    var savedObj = DbContext.Employees.Add(obj);
                    DbContext.SaveChanges();
                    savedId = savedObj.ID;
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < Parameters.Length; i++)
                {
                    Models.EmployeeDetail obj = new Models.EmployeeDetail;
                    obj.ID = Convert.ToInt32(savedId);
                    obj.KEY = Parameters[i].Key;
                    obj.VALUE = Parameters[i].Value;
                    DbContext.EmployeeDetails.Add(obj);
                    DbContext.SaveChanges();
                    DbContext.EmployeeDetails.Remove(obj);
                }
```

Please suggest how can I make this work correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking at the mapping of model structure with DB, released that Model is incorrectly structured. Issue was with Model not having key(primary) definition. After associating correct key sequence, the issue is resolved.

Hope this will help someone who is looking into similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Detach the current state of your entity and change the next state call. Add a Detached line of code after `Savechanges()`:

```
db.Entry(your entity).State = EntityState.Added;
db.SaveChanges();
db.Entry(your entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
```